# Putting classes in a DLL?

Tags: delphi, class, dll, delphi-xe

Is it possible to put some classes into a DLL?

I have several custom classes in a project I am working on and would like to have them put in a DLL and then accessed in the main application when needed, plus if they are in a DLL I can reuse these classes in other projects if I need to.

I found this link: http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=84394 which discusses accessing classes in a DLL and it mentions delegating to a class-type property but I could not find any further information on this in the Delphi help or online.

Is there any reason I should not put classes in a DLL, and if it is ok is there a better way of doing it then in the example from the link above?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not possible to get a Class/Instance from a DLL.
Instead of the class you can hand over an interface to the class.
Below you find a simple example

```
// The Interface-Deklaration for Main and DLL
unit StringFunctions_IntfU;

interface

type
  IStringFunctions = interface
    ['{240B567B-E619-48E4-8CDA-F6A722F44A71}']
    function CopyStr( const AStr : WideString; Index, Count : Integer ) : WideString;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

The simple DLL

```
library StringFunctions;

uses
  StringFunctions_IntfU; // use Interface-Deklaration

{$R *.res}

type
  TStringFunctions = class( TInterfacedObject, IStringFunctions )
  protected
    function CopyStr( const AStr : WideString; Index : Integer; Count : Integer ) : WideString;
  end;

  { TStringFunctions }

function TStringFunctions.CopyStr( const AStr : WideString; Index, Count : Integer ) : WideString;
begin
  Result := Copy( AStr, Index, Count );
end;

function GetStringFunctions : IStringFunctions; stdcall; export;
begin
  Result := TStringFunctions.Create;
end;

exports
  GetStringFunctions;

begin
end.
```

And now the simple Main Program

```
uses
  StringFunctions_IntfU;  // use Interface-Deklaration

// Static link to external function
function GetStringFunctions : IStringFunctions; stdcall; external 'StringFunctions.dll' name 'GetStringFunctions';

procedure TMainView.Button1Click( Sender : TObject );
begin
  Label1.Caption := GetStringFunctions.CopyStr( Edit1.Text, 1, 5 );
end;
```

Comment: Whilst this is certainly a viable way to call code in a DLL, it doesn't actually answer the question. Which was "Is it possible to put some classes into a DLL?"

Comment: @David Heffernan If you reduce it to the question, then you are totally right, the answer is: no way.

Comment: If I were you, I'd edit your answer to that effect. Just a single sentence right at the top. And then the rest of your answer, outlining a good way to solve the actual problem, is still excellent.

Comment: "Reducing it to the question" is how StackOverflow works. You answer the question asked, which is why I didn't include interfaces as a solution. :-) Nice answer, but it needs to address the question asked first.

Comment: @Ken ok, i understand, that Runtime-Packages match the Question "Is it possible to put some classes into a DLL?" and Interfaced Access to a class from a DLL did not ... i'm impressed how so works or did i catch it wrong?

Comment: Yes. :-) There's a difference between "bundle your classes in a package instead of a DLL" and "rewrite all your classes so they have interfaces and use those instead (which means changing all your code that uses those classes also)". :-)

Comment: But a Runtime Package is no DLL, and the question was about DLL

Answer (score 5):

Use runtime packages for this purpose; it's exactly what they're designed for in the first place. They get loaded automatically (or can be loaded manually), and automatically set up the sharing of the same memory manager so you can freely use classes and types between them.

You're much better off using packages (which is exactly what the IDE does for much of its functionality for that very reason).

Comment: You really can't import classes that are defined in a DLL in Delphi. Aside from all the hurdles to overcome even if you could, there's just no language support. You can't use `external` inside a class. There's no `__declspec(dllimport)` for Delphi classes.

Comment: @David: The question never asked about importing, and I didn't mention exporting. The question asked about "putting some classes in a DLL", which is in fact possible, and using them from an app (which again is possible with a considerable amount of extra work).

Comment: Importing and exporting go hand in hand. Using them from an app means exporting from the DLL and importing into the app. I'm sure you know all this. The point is that neither exporting nor importing is actually possible when the code lives in a DLL. There is no Delphi language support for this. You cannot include a method in an exports statement, not use `external` on a method. So your middle paragraph is factually inaccurate.

Comment: @David: The only thing "factually inaccurate" is the mistake in phrasing in "You can do the same thing", which should be "You can use a DLL". I'll fix that, because they are obviously not "the same thing". Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you can use a DLL, but you can't, from the app, call methods on classes that are defined in the DLL.

Comment: David, you can in fact do so. That's the reason there's a requirement for ShareMem, is to make classes compatible between them. I don't have any code handy (because I would never do it that way), but there has been code posted before in the old Borland newsgroups that demonstrates doing so.

Comment: @David: I stand corrected. I can't find a link to support it, so I'll remove that portion from my answer. If I find one later, I'll roll back to the pre-edit version and include it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi does not support either importing or exporting classes from DLLs. To import a class from another module, you need to use packages.

Answer (score 3):

While the official answer is "*you can't*", anything is possible of course. Frameworks like Remobjects SDK and Remobjects Hydra has been doing this for a long time. The problem is that it requires you to create an infrastructure around such a system, which is not something Delphi deals with out of the box.

The first step is memory management. A DLL is injected into the process loading it, but it does not share memory management. It has to be this way since a DLL can be created in a myriad of languages, each with their own internal mechanisms. This poses a problem with safety (i.e program writing into DLL memory and visa versa).

Secondly, interface (read: content description). How will your application know what classes it can create, class members, parameter types and so on. This is why COM requires type-libraries, which describe the content of a DLL.

Third, life-time management. If memory management for the objects created from a DLL is handled by the DLL, the DLL must also release said objects.

The above steps already exists and it's called COM. You are of course free to create as many COM DLL files as you please, just remember that these have to be registered with Windows before you use them. Either "on the fly" by your application (if you have the security rights to do so) or by your installer.
This is why COM, while representing the ultimate plugin system, is rarely used by Delphi programmers, because the technical cost of using it as a plugin system outweighs the benefits.

**The alternative way**

If you can assure that your DLL's are only to be used by Delphi programs, then you have a second way to explore. You have to create methods to share the memory manager of your main program with the DLL (Remobjects does this). This allows you to share objects, strings and more between the DLL and the main application.

You can then use RTTI to "map" classes stored in the DLL (the DLL must do this and generate both class and method tables) which can be invoked through a proxy class you device yourself.

All in all, unless you have plenty of free time to waste, I would either buy a system like Remobjects Hydra - or stick with packages. But can it be done another way? Of course it can. But at the cost of time and hard work.